# create data frame column based on calculation using column.max

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
                        Nets  plot_height
2018-04-01 11:35:47  30000.6          250
2018-04-02 11:35:47  10000.5          250
2018-04-03 11:35:47  70000.5          250
2018-04-04 11:35:47   9000.8          250
2018-04-05 11:35:47  20000.5          250
```

I want to add another column "ratio" that is calculated by the df['Nets'].max divided by df['plot_height]

I tried

```
max_nets = df['Nets'].max
df['ratio'] = df['Nets'] / max_nets
```

that errors with: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'method'

Comment: `max_nets = df['Nets'].max` --> `max_nets = df['Nets'].max()`, with the `()`. You didn't _call_ the function/method, just bound it to another name.

Comment: @roganjosh that did the trick.  thank you